# Why is adding a NOT NULL column with a default constraint instantaneous?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, alter-table, ddl

```
CREATE TABLE TestTab (ID INT IDENTITY(1,1), st nvarchar(100))

INSERT INTO TestTab (st) values ('a')
INSERT INTO TestTab (st) values ('b')
INSERT INTO TestTab (st) values ('c')
INSERT INTO TestTab (st) values ('d')
INSERT INTO TestTab (st) values ('e')

INSERT INTO TestTab (st) SELECT TOP 10000 st from testtab
GO 30

ALTER TABLE TestTab ADD newcol nvarchar(10) DEFAULT 'newcol'
UPDATE TestTab SET newcol = 'newcol'  --6 sec
ALTER TABLE TestTab ADD newcol1 nvarchar(10) DEFAULT 'newcol1' NOT NULL

DROP TABLE TestTab
```

When I execute this test script, the `ALTER` with `UPDATE` takes 6 seconds which is understandable.

However, the `ALTER` with the `DEFAULT NOT NULL` executes instantaneously even on a much larger table. Is there any explanation on why this is instantaneous? On the physical disk, data still needs to be written to all rows right?

I tried looking at `SET STATISTICS IO ON` and the Query plan, however those dont seem to be available for DDL operations.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Yes, adding a column with NOT NULL and a default doesn't actually write the values to all the rows at the time of the alter, so it is no longer a size-of-data operation. When you select from the table, the columns are actually materialized from [sys.system_internals_partition_columns](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189600.aspx), which prevents all the values from having to be written (until they are changed). Note that this doesn't work for all data types and requires Enterprise Edition.

[Remus Rusanu](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/708/remus-rusanu?tab=profile) explains this in more detail here:

- [Online non-NULL with values column add in SQL Server 2012](http://rusanu.com/2011/07/13/online-non-null-with-values-column-add-in-sql-server-11/)

Also, for an `ALTER` at least, we still can't show you a plan because SQL Server doesn't produce one, but to see I/O, you can use [SQL Sentry Plan Explorer](https://www.sqlsentry.com/products/plan-explorer/sql-server-query-view).* This screen shot shows adding a column, c5, "online" as described above, and then another column, c6, "offline" because LOB types are not supported. You can see the I/O is mostly expressed as reads rather than writes, but what's more telling is the (invalid!) `UPDATE` associated with the offline alter.

> [image: I/O for online vs. offline alter]

If you don't have Enterprise Edition, both statements will have the secondary `UPDATE` attached (and the associated reads). (And if you use the free version of Plan Explorer, which doesn't get the full query call stack, you won't see the above - you will just see an empty statement tree. A paid version is required to see the full query call stack.)

Note that SQL Server will produce an *estimated* plan, but it's not very useful. At all. And the estimated plan for an online alter is identical to the estimated plan for an offline alter.

> [image: Plan diagram for online alter]

*<sub>*Disclaimer: I work for SQL Sentry.*</sub>

Comment: +1: esp. for "Enterprise Edition".  I have always wondered why it didn't work at some of my customer sites ...